# Get option title from dropdown list with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I got a dynamic input form from a dropdown list. Here's my code for the dropdown

```
<label class="strong">Cut: 
<select name="add_qty">
<?php
    $qqs = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM m_maincut WHERE maincut_status = '1'");
    while($roq = mysqli_fetch_array($qqs, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
?>
        <option id="opsi" value="<?php echo $roq['maincut_id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $roq['maincut_name']; ?>"><?php echo $roq['maincut_name']; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
</label> 
Total: <input type="text" name="add_name" /> 
<input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add New" />
```

and here's my javascript to make the form dynamic (click button for add more option)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNum = 0;

function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum++;
    var text = frm.opsi.title;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum' + rowNum + '">Nama Biaya: <option type="text" name="qty[]" size="4" value="' + frm.add_qty.value + '">' + text + '</option> Jumlah: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="' + frm.add_name.value + '"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow(' + rowNum + ');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
}
</script>
```

Here's my result:

[image]

"Tambah ke Biaya" means "Add More"

**My question is**, how to get the title of the option? I can get the value, but I can get the title to show up to client. Because if I show the value, it will show only number (the ID's)

Comment: What's the HTML produced by that PHP, because *that's* what the JavaScript will be working on, PHP is irrelevant in the browser. Also, when and where do you want to retrieve the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get innerHTML of the option tag if you want to get which is shown to the user. And you must create an option instead a p element

Comment: In the addRow function. In the js

Comment: Change the code var text to : var text = document.getElementById("opsi").innerHTML;

Answer (score 1):

To get the title attribute of tag,

```
var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
```

To get html inside `<option>`,

```
var html = jQuery(this).html();
```

And suggest you to use jQuery, it will be easier

```
<input id="add_new" type="button" value="Add New" />
```

and trigger click event of this button like,

```
jQuery('#add_new').click(function(){
    // your process
});
```

Comment: you have to use those inside context as i shown in my edit, also note that you can use any selector instead `this` to `.class` or `#id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really looking for the title's value, since title is one of the element's attribute, you should be able to use

```
jQuery('your-selector').attr('title');
```